# Length of tangent that meets sin of a larger triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm looking for a formula to find the length CG which is a tangent of the triangle ABC up to where it touches the triangle AEF. How can I find that? I'm working with values `AB = 4`, `AF = 5` and `FE = 1` but the value itself doesn't matter as much as the formula.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to see if you re-drew with all points labelled A, B, etc. and then you might want length EG for example. Note if you don't specify any of the lengths the whole figure could be expanded and thus all lengths change.

Comment: I'm looking for a formula and not specifically for the length. Ill add labels to the points.

Comment: Is your line thru E supposed to be parallel to AF or is that unknown?

Comment: It is parallel to AF, yes. I've actually just realized that ACG is a right triangle with adjacent side AC. I think I can calculate CG from that